# Unable to get htmlelement from managed ie browser from vb6

Tags: vb6

I am modifying a IE automation program
I am trying to get clicked html elements in an html page from an existing vb6 program.

I am able to get all the elements except the following drop down button menus as shown in the image below

[Example Htmlpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JtOD.png)

When I am clicking the "Actions" dropdown menu and then clicking on menu item "Export to Excel" or any other menu the doc.activeelement.innertext is returning it "Actions" instead of "Export to Excel"

Here is my VB code

```
Public WithEvents IE As InternetExplorer
Private WithEvents doc As HTMLDocument
Private Function Doc_onclick() As Boolean
    me.grid1.cell(1,j)=doc.activeelement.tagname & "::" doc.activeelement.innertext 
    Doc_onclick = True
End Function
```

Here is the relevant section of HTML code rendering that dropdown menu of the said page

```html
<div id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:j_id12" class="x6e" style="overflow: hidden; width: 167px;">
  <div class="xde">
    <div id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:j_id12::oc" class="af_menuBar_content">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="">
        <tr>
          <td class="x19v">
            <a style="display: none;"></a>
            <div id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:ATm" _afrdth="1" _afrgrp="0" class="xg2 xkj">
              <div class="x1b7" tabindex="0">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="">
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="x19w">
                      <a class="xfn" href="#" onclick="return false" tabindex="-1">
         Actions</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <div class="xg3">
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <table id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:ATm::menu" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="x1a7" style="display: none;" summary="">
                <tr>
                  <td id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:ATm::sUpBg" class="x26x p_AFDisabled">
                    <div id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:ATm::ScrollUp" class="x1a8 p_AFDisabled" style="display: none">
                      <span class="x1aa"></span>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:ATm::ScrollBox" class="x1ba">
                      <table id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:ATm::ScrollContent" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="af_menu_scroll-content" summary="" width="100%">
                        <tr id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:editMenuItem" _afrdth="2" _afrgrp="0" class="x1a2 x1ab p_AFDisabled" onclick="return false;">
                          <td class="x1ae">
                            <div class="x1bb">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="x1af">Edit Supplier</td>
                          <td class="x1ag">
                            <div class="x1bb">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="x1ah">
                            <div class="x1bb">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="x1ay">
                          <td class="x1aa">
                            <div class="x1az">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td colspan="3">
                            <div class="x1b0">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:ATexm" _afrdth="2" _afrgrp="1" class="x1a2 x1ab" onclick="return false;" tabindex="0" title="Export to Excel">
                          <td class="x1ae">
                            <div class="x1bb">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="x1af">Export to Excel</td>
                          <td class="x1ag">
                            <div class="x1bb">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="x1ah">
                            <div class="x1bb">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="x1ay">
                          <td class="x1aa">
                            <div class="x1az">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td colspan="3">
                            <div class="x1b0">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:cmi1" _afrdth="2" _afrgrp="2" class="x1a2 x1ab p_AFDisabled" onclick="return false;">
                          <td class="x1ae">
                            <div class="x1bb">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="x1af">View Administrative Contacts</td>
                          <td class="x1ag">
                            <div class="x1bb">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="x1ah">
                            <div class="x1bb">
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:ATm::sDwnBg" class="x26y">
                    <div id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:ATm::ScrollDown" class="x1a9" style="display: none">
                      <span class="x1aa"></span>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="x19v">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:_vw::sDwnBg" class="x26y">
            <div id="pt1:USma:0:MAt1:0:pt1:r1:0:AP1:r8:0:AT1:_ATp:_vw::ScrollDown" class="x1a9" style="display: none">
              <span class="x1aa"></span>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have also tried frames but didn't succeed.

Can someone help me in capturing the clicked elements in managed IE browser?

I can't change the HTML code of the page since it's not ours.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get the clicked element:

```
Dim oSrcEl As MSHTML.HTMLUnknownElement
Set oSrcEl = doc.parentWindow.event.srcElement
```

If you want get an attribute of a parent element (maybe you will want to get the parent *tr* element, because it has *id*):

```
Dim oDomAttr As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMAttribute
Set oDomAttr = Nothing
Do
  Set oDomAttr = oSrcEl.Attributes.getNamedItem("id") 'attribute what i'm searching for
  Set oSrcEl = oSrcEl.parentElement 'parent element
'either I have found element with id attribute 
'or I'm at the top without success
Loop While oDomAttr Is Nothing And (Not oSrcEl Is Nothing)
```